# Kotlin URL().readText() crashes application

Tags: android, string, multithreading, kotlin, url

I'm trying to get some text from my website and toast it, but I get `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadError` when running

```
var str = URL("https://server.necrodragon41.repl.co/server/connect").readText(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

And the app crashes. Here is my code:

```
RegisterBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (day.toString() != "0" && month.toString() != "0" && year.toString() != "0") {
                try {
                    var t = Thread(Runnable {
                        var str = URL("https://server.necrodragon41.repl.co/server/connect").readText(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    })
                    t.start()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                ErrorText.text = "The date is invalid."
                ErrorText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

I tried making the thread because i got toasted the error (before putting the code into a thread). How can I get the string without crashing the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On android you can not make network requests on the (UI/Main)Thread, that would freeze the application.

To handle this cases that you need to use a different thread.
Since you are using kotlin, you may do something like:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // network call
    }
}
```

This uses lifecycle extensions, so in order to use it, please add
`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"` on your app level build.gradle

You can also use Java Executors.

```
private val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

// use the executor on method
executor.execute {
   // network call
   runOnUiThread { 
       // update UI
   }
}
```

Also, since network needs to be handled outside main thread, UI changes must happen on UI thread.

Since it seems like you are stating on android, if you have the time, please read the [Arch Guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide). There is a nice course by Google on [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012).

Comment: The app crashes the same when I use `executors` and the program does not recognize `lifecycleScope`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that although networt requests need to run on another thread, interface related changes need to run on (UI/Main) Thread.

Comment: To use lifecycleScope, you need to add the Jetpack Lifecycle dependency on the app level build.gradle: 
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"